# Removing row numbers from matrix array in R

Tags: r

I am trying to print a matrix array which is made up of one column put when I print it it shows the row number.
I need to print this column next to the same column but with the lowest value taken out and take them away from each other like below.

a. b. a-b

b. c. b-c

c. d. c-d

d

when I call the matrix it prints row numbers. is there a way to remove this[image]

Comment: `rownames(matrix)=NULL` may do the job

Comment: `write.table(matrix, row.names=F)` is a  way without removing the names from the matrix.

Comment: You should provide reproducible data, not pictures, and the code you are using. Your print output did not come from a matrix since since the row numbers are not in brackets. It probably comes from a data frame. Using the `print()` function explicitly with `row.names=FALSE` should work.